# Neo4j Edge Multiplicity Settings

Tags: neo4j

Is there a way in Neo4j 3 to set edge multiplicity settings for edges with a given label or property?

For example, if I had a "biological mother" relationship, I would want to enforce a many-to-one edge multiplicity for relationships of this type.

I'm looking for something similar as the edge multiplicity settings [in JanusGraph](http://docs.janusgraph.org/0.2.0/schema.html#_edge_label_multiplicity).

As a follow up question, what setting values are available if defining edge multiplicity is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neo4j currently doesn't have constraints to support this kind of usage (restricting edge multiplicity on nodes of a given label). You could do this yourself, however.

You could do this via APOC Procedures by [adding a trigger](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_triggers) that can check, when you add a relationship of the given type to a node, that the nodes linked adhere your expected multiplicity limits.

If you want to do this without APOC, you would need to create a TransactionEventHandler to perform the check, and then you'd need to create a kernel extension for the purpose of loading your TransactionEventHandler instance. Here's a [blog entry describing this approach](https://maxdemarzi.com/2015/03/25/triggers-in-neo4j/).